# How to get multiple value in one row in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

I have database table name emp_leave in postgreSQL9.4 like

| emp_name | leave_type | total_lday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tame | PL | 3 |
| Tame | UL | 4 |

I want the query result like

| emp_name | paid_leave | unpaid_leave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tame | 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgresql 9.4 also has the `FILTER` clause to do conditional aggregation:

```
select emp_name, 
       max(total_lday) FILTER (where leave_type = 'PL') as paid_leave,
       max(total_lday) FILTER (where leave_type = 'UL') as unpaid_leave
from emp_leave
group by emp_name
```

(ANSI SQL-2016, Feature T612, “Advanced OLAP operations”.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try below - using conditional aggregation

```
select emp_name, 
  max(case when leave_type='PL' then total_lday end) as paid_leave,
  max(case when leave_type='UL' then total_lday end) as unpaid_leave
from emp_leave
group by emp_name
```